# spring mvc with Hibernate BootStrap select option value not populating

Tags: html, spring, twitter-bootstrap, hibernate

In my project I am using Spring mvc with hibernate and for ui bootstrap..

I have in UI part :

```
<div class='form-group'>
<label class='control-label col-md-2 col-md-offset-2'
        for='id_equipment'>Department</label>
    <div class='col-md-8'>
    <div class='col-md-3'>
    <div class='form-group internal'>
    <select class='form-control'  id='${student.student_department}'>
    <option>cse</option>
    <option>Fifth wheel</option>
    <option>Electrical</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

My requirement is: when Student want to add details that time in the department list will appear as a dropdown .
student can select the value and can add the value and when Student want to update details.. from database department will appear first of the list when he/she already selected..But I am getting error in this lines.
Howw to populate value to the select tag in bootstrap with spring mvc?

When I try to add details I am getting null value from select paths.

Comment: Kindly be more specific. The error logs are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Add `value="some-value"` to your options. E.g.

```
<option value="cse">cse</option>
<option value="5th">Fifth wheel</option>
<option value="Electrical">Electrical</option>
```